# Problems with my Ruby Version Manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, sqlite

I am taking a Ruby course and somehow I ended up without the ability to bundle my ruby files. I showed by instructor my terminal and he said that there was a conflict between sqlite 3 and the versions of ruby installed. He thinks there's a problem between ruby and sqlite 3 and ruby. He just isn't sure what's causing it. Hopefully someone in here can tell me what's going on with this.

```
RVM reloaded!
Macs-MacBook-Pro:testapp mac$ rails server
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

Comment: Are you using bundler?

Answer (score 0):

I already had this problem. It solved with a reinstall of ruby and openssl on my OSX :

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Be sure to have the `osx-gcc-installer` on your mac !